# How to create a dict of list from list of dicts in a functional way in python

Tags: python, scala, functional-programming

I've moved from scala to python to train deep learning models. I'm missing some of the expressiveness of a functional approaches to data manipulation most notably  `group by`. 
I would like to split a set / list of files (pathlib.Path objects) to 2 sets: validation and training. I have a function `which_set` that associated a set name for every file.  In scala I would write:

```
>>> all_paths = TRAIN_PATH.glob('*')
>>> all_paths.groupby(which_set) 
{'valid': [....], 'train': [....]}
```

In python I struggle. I could use pandas and it's `groupby` method, but then I would have to convert `all_paths` to strings. Not ideal. I could use itertools but it calls which_set multiple times for each element:

```
from itertools import groupby
{k : list(l) for k, l in groupby(sorted(all_paths, key=which_set), key=which_set)}
```

This code seems more pythonic but it isn't functional, and it is hard to read (compared to scala version)

```
paths = {}
for x in all_paths: paths.setdefault(which_set(x), []).append(x)
```

Do you know of any library or an approach that could help me here?

Comment: I think I'm getting lost in unfamiliar territory, but when I need to do a train/test split, I use sklearn's `train_test_split()`

Comment: even if you were doing it in scala, it's unapplausable to use groupby for splitting binary. `.partition` on the other hand, should be a properer function to use.

Comment: Python isn't a particularly functional language, if you insist on writing purely functional code, it's not going to make it easy for you

Comment: Anyway, the *idiomatic* way of grouping into a `dict` is to use `grouper = collections.defaultdict(list)` and then simply `for x in all_paths: grouper[which_set(x)].append(x)`... which is pretty readable to my eyes

Comment: Also, is calling `which_set` twice for each element really that big of a deal that you don't want to use `groupby(sorted(..., key=f), key=f)`?

Comment: I know just the guy to answer this one :D

Comment: Note, you can avoid calling `which_set` twice if it really bothers use by materializing a list of `tuple` objects, and grouping that: `keyed_paths = sorted((which_set(p), p) for p in all_paths)`, then using the `operator` module, `{k : [x for _, x in l] for k, l in groupby(keyed_paths, key=operator.itemgetter(0))}`

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga, how about making an answer so I can accept it?